# Yeoman working very slowly loading pages

Tags: node.js, yeoman

I'm working on a project that uses Yeoman
it's been working great on my machine till recently some changes have been made to the project (introducing angular mainly) while I wasn't working on it for a month.

since I came back every page load has been taking around 2 mins only to get HTMLs and JS files!
the cpu is between 30%-50% physical memory around 60%, the computer is in good shapes.
other people working on the same project are getting very fast load times..

what can it be?
10x!
Igal

Comment: anyone?
any performance tips would be great.. it's really slowing down my work..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the problem is on your side, therefore I would just delete the whole mess and check it out again, I assume you use some kind of Version Control.

If this does not work, it could be some caching problems - but it is hard to say with the current information.

Do you have anything that the others don't?

I would also make sure to update Yeoman, Node.js ect. to the lastest version, or just the same as your co-workers.

For extra performance you can disable the force option in the gruntfile, but seeing as the other people on your project has no problems this should not do anything about your situation.